# Powershell Double $$ in Variable - Using .replace

Tags: powershell, replace, windows-server-2008, powershell-3.0

We currently have a script that generates random passwords and we utilize another function to read from this password list for various tasks.  While using these passwords they are passed into a variable let's call `$password`.  So,

`$password = FindPassword "blah"`

If I were to print `$password` then it would return say, `Q@48$$!y@&$^`

The issue with this, is when I replace a word in a file using `$password` it is missing one of the `$` so, `Q@48$!y@&$^`

Here is the code I am using for the replace,

```
(Get-Content $Some_File) |
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "PASSWORD","${Password}"} | Set-Content $Some_File
```

Anyone know of a way to show two $$ in a row?  I have tried using something like this to ensure special characters are treated appropriately, but can't get the $ to work:

```
$password = $password.Replace("`^","`^")
$password = $password.Replace("`@","`@")
$password = $password.Replace("`&","`&")
$password = $password.Replace("`!","`!")
$password = $password.Replace("\`$","\`$")
```

Also,

```
$password = $password.Replace("`$","``$")
```

Will work, but if the password is different the next time around, it is only unique to this particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `-replace` operator with the `.replace()` method, it does the trick:

```
(Get-Content $Some_File) |
    Foreach-Object { $_.toString().Replace("PASSWORD", $password.ToString()) } | Set-Content $Some_File
```

Comment: Sorry for the redundant use of the word 'replace'.  :)